# Dark Magical Circle vs Masked HERO Blast

Tags: yu-gi-oh

My friend and I were playing Dark Magician vs HERO. I had Masked HERO Blast on the field and he activated Dark Magical Circle (DMC). I chained Blast's effect to return the Dark Magical Circle to my opponent's hand. I thought that since DMC has to remain face up on the field for its effect to resolve, he wouldn't get to look the top 3 cards of his deck. Since DMC states that a player may only "USE" each of its effects once per turn, even if my friend had played the circle again, he wouldn't have been able to use the first effect to look up the top cards of the deck because he had already used it once (and it resolved without effect).

The question is, was this interaction ok? Or would he had been able to look up the top 3 cards anyway (by activating circle immediately after being returned to the hand). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since "Dark Magical Circle" stated:

> You can only use each effect of "Dark Magical Circle" once per turn.

No, he cannot use "Dark Magical Circle" to look at the top deck again at the same turn.

However, they are allowed to activate it again as a Continuous Spell, and use the effect to banish your card if "Dark Magician" is Summoned.